# Is it possible to constrain LGBM models to ensure non-negative "Shap contribution" value for features?

Tags: python, regression, constraints, lightgbm, shap

I am running a LGBM model for a regression problem and then using 'Shap' package to identify the contribution of the different features.

My problem is that 'Shap' is giving me 'negative' contribution of certain features, which in real-life can NOT be negative. (i.e. The Feature can only have a positive or zero contribution in explaining the target variable).

I wanted to request if anybody has experience in constraining the LGBM model in a way that 'feature contributoins' are either positive or zero ?

Thanks so much for your advise

i have tried running multiple LGBM models with different hyperparameters (max depth, num_leaves, reg_lambda, random_state) to check what combinations leads to non-negative Shap values, but all in vain.

I have also tried multiple different features as input to LGBM models, but all in vain as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You seem to confuse model and explanation. It is your responsibility as a modeler to make a meaningful model. SHAP simply provides an explanation of the model. So you can, e.g., set a monotonicity constraint on a certain feature to ensure that the model does the right thing. This guarantees that the predictions are monotonic in that feature, Ceteris Paribus.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I think i wasnt clear enough. I do understand Shap is just an explanation. My problem is with the LGBM model itself and i am not sure why LGBM model creates a non-intuitive prediction. Would you have any advise on how to constraint/tune the LGBM model to ensure a realistic prediction ? Thanks

Comment: "The Feature can only have a positive or zero contribution in explaining the target variable" that's not now this works, even if you add monotonic constraints. If larger values of a feature lead to larger predictions, then lower values of the feature lead to lower predictions. And since shap compared everything to the global average, you will get both positive and negative shap values for (almost?) every feature.

Comment: For such a thing you need a negative class with all 0 features, and a positive class where all features point to a positive direction

Comment: Thanks Ben. I realized the same thing. Shap values by definition will be negative for some features as it is compared to the global average. Thank you!!